# MacOS Ventura - mounting local NFS share to root directory with help of synthetic.conf

Tags: macos, ventura, nfs

I already figured a way, and it kinda works, but it just feels wrong. Is there a more proper way to do it?

I recently upgraded from Mojave to Ventura and suddenly realized I lost all my root folders, and I'm no longer able to create one. I dug through Q&A and found info about `/etc/synthetic.conf` - but it could easily create symlinks only, and I found out that `typescript-eslint` for example cannot work with root symlinks, it needs real directory.

My later research resulted in either local `NFS` share or `macFUSE` `bindfs`. I tried first, because it is already installed and seems easier. I had `/work` and `/data` directories and I moved them to `/opt/work` and `/opt/data`.

Created NFS share:

- `/etc/exports`

```
/opt/data /opt/work 127.0.0.1 ::1
```

- `sudo launchctl start com.apple.rpcbind`
- `sudo nfsd enable`
- `sudo nfsd stop`
- `sudo nfsd start`

Created empty mount points in root directory:

- `/etc/synthetic.conf`

```
data
work
```

Restarted, checked, mount points are created, and `showmount -e` is ok.

Manual NFS mounting is ok too `sudo mount -t nfs 127.0.0.1:/opt/data /data`, checked, `sudo umount /data`

Now I'm trying to mount these on startup.

#### First

I tried `/etc/fstab` - it is not mounted on restart, and `sudo automount -cv` shows weird error `automount: /data points to unexpected location /data, instead of /System/Volumes/Data/data` and it also creates symlink `/System/Volumes/Data/data -> /opt/data`. Root `/data` remains empty. Here is my part of `/etc/fstab`

```
127.0.0.1:/opt/data /data nfs rw,actimeo=1,hard,bg
127.0.0.1:/opt/work /work nfs rw,actimeo=1,hard,bg
```

#### Second

I tried `/etc/auto_master`. I got the same error as above, and after a lot of trial and error I came to this solution:

- my part of `/etc/auto_master`

```
/-          /etc/auto_nfs
```

- `/etc/auto_nfs`

```
/System/Volumes/Data/../../../data -fstype=nfs,rw,actimeo=1,hard,bg 127.0.0.1:/opt/data
/System/Volumes/Data/../../../work -fstype=nfs,rw,actimeo=1,hard,bg 127.0.0.1:/opt/work
```

It works, persisted between reboots and `sudo automount -cv` shows proper

```
automount: /System/Volumes/Data/home updated (/home -> /System/Volumes/Data/home)
automount: /data updated
automount: /work updated
automount: no unmounts
```

Is there a proper not hacky way to do this? Why it disallows to mount at root, and expects `/System/Volumes/Data`? I found some info that you can do `data /System/Volumes/Data/data` in `/etc/synthetic.conf` and then mount NFS to `/System/Volumes/Data/data` - but again - there will be symlink at root.

Comment: Unfortunately, with this NFS mount I ended up with my entire `/work` folder filled with dot underscore ._ xattr metadata files created for every file I modify. I didn't find a way to prevent this or to forward xattrs to NFS server on same machine. Now I could only use `synthetic.conf` symlinks and move all my configurations to their new physical locations at `/opt`. Sad.

Comment: Not being familiar with `typescript-eslint` specifically, why in the world does it want a directory off the root?

Comment: There are unresolved set of issues, like this: https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/2234 or https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/2987 which they probably won't fix. Basically they dereference symlink to get real file, and then compare path of real file and symlink path and threat these as different files.

Comment: Neither of those talks about the software needing directories off the root.  Is this an "I want"?

Comment: Actually both yes and no. When I first created directory structure on my Mac 10 years ago, I came there with Windows/Linux background, where you have some freedom of your directory structure, so I created /work and /data where I keep all my stuff (work/hobby projects, firefox/thunderbird profiles, irc logs, etc..). This was my fault. Now I have symlinks, some programs support it, some not, I have not working feature here, inconvience there, And I have to migrate all my data somewhere else, and moving it is a pain. I have to destroy and recreate all profiles in many programs I use.